# Capture event when user clicks on x axis on Google charts

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, google-visualization

I am using [Angular Google Charts](https://github.com/FERNman/angular-google-charts). I am working on a requirement where I need to change the format of x axis values when user clicks on them. Like absolute value <=> Percentage Value.
Is there any way I can capture the event when user clicks anywhere on x axis and not other parts of chart?

I tried angular's (click) event however It is not giving me any information as which part of the chart is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

depends on the chart being used,
most charts in the `'corechart'` package have a `'click'` event.
check the [events](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#events) section in the docs for the particular chart.

the `'click'` event will receive an argument with a `targetID` of the chart element clicked.
when a x-axis label is clicked, the `targetID` will have the following form.

```
hAxis#0#label#0
```

where the first `0` is the index of the axis (always zero when there is only one x-axis)
and the second `0` is the index of the label clicked.

so the following would indicate the second x-axis label, on the first x-axis, was clicked.

```
hAxis#0#label#1
```

as such, we can use a regex expression to determine if any x-axis label was clicked.

```
/hAxis#(\d+)#label#(\d+)/
```

see following working snippet,
click the chart to see the result.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y0');

  for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    var direction = (i % 2 === 0) ? 1 : -1;
    data.addRow([i, (2 * i * direction)]);
  }

  var options = {
    curveType: 'function'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'click', function(e) {
    var match = e.targetID.match(/hAxis#(\d+)#label#(\d+)/);
    if ((match !== null) && (match.length > 0)) {
      console.log('x-axis label -->', e.targetID);
    } else {
      console.log('not x-axis label -->', e.targetID);
    }
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```